# Android button effects and animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-button, android-styles

In my next project i want button effect or animation like this when user click on button or drag hover the button.

I do too many research but i found nothing.

I want button effect like this.

[image]

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: @mvai thanks for respond. I want button background animation like shown in the pic, When user click on the any part of button so all the line move like that in button.

Comment: @mvai, all the line must move only that side where user click any part of button or drag hover it

Comment: So we have a view with lots of lines that change direction based on user tap..? But we still need to know, like, how many lines to draw upon this view.

Comment: @mvai, actually i am new in android so i dont know much about android development. And i also dont know how many lines are there, Number of lines are based on the height of the view.

Comment: I think that you understand my problem, Yes i want the change direction where user tap on the view and also when he drag over it. Please help me.

Comment: Where are you implementing this? Code will differ based on whether you have to implement in app or in a game. Morever what are these lines for? From what i can tell this image is from material design page which tells how material behaves in lollipop. The actual lines won't be there during animation.

Comment: @redsnowfox thanks for response, Yeah i have to implement this design into my app not in game. may be first time when view is display the line not be there, but i want that line direction when user click on view or drag hover the view.

Comment: @redsnowfox, you are right i take that image from android material design page. It is possible to apply that type of animation to any view when user click the view or drag hover the view. Please help

Comment: I think you meant CircularReaveal Animation?

Comment: use famo.us framework

Comment: thanks you @RandykaYudhistira, but how can i used that in android ? Please can you give me any example of it?

Comment: The lines? That's not even a real animation in the material design! Just some fancy spec of how a user should perceive button-touch animations. I suggest looking at the API samples or following tutorials in the [Android Guides](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html), that would help a lot in getting you started.

Comment: Yeah exactly-- that image from [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#) has no explanation beyond "Goals-- Create a visual language that synthesizes classic principles of good design with the innovation and possibility of technology and science" Hilarious.

Answer (score 4):

To create animation similar to your example you will definitely need to implement custom animations. Find details here:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Also you should definitely check for existing libraries that might imlement similar effects. Nice libraries source:

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/13

Comment: thanks @Ivan, ok let me check and i will try to implement that

Answer (score 3):

Here is basic animation for button effect :
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/02/apply-animation-on-button.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use "**FrameLayout**" clickable and also **inside it** use **imageview** and you then easily animate the image.

**Structure**

```
<FrameLayout
 //set the properties + must set clickable property  
>
   <ImageView 
    // Set the required property 
   />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Then set click Listener of framelayout and where you need to animate imageview** inside .java file.

Create a animatation xml in anim folder

my_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite" />
```

then call this in .java file with the imageview
like given below for smooth rotation of image.

```
 Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.my_anim);

            a.setDuration(1000);

            myImageView.startAnimation(a);


            a.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {

                private final int frameCount = 50;

                @Override
                public float getInterpolation(float input) {

                    return (float) Math.floor(input * frameCount) / frameCount;

                }
            });
```

Comment: but how i animate the image like show in above image, Please give the sample code of it

Comment: @KalpeshRajai i have edit my answer now you understand how it work you can change the variable values according to your need.
happy development. :)